# point_cloud2.read_points and then?

Tags: python, rospy, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a topic publishing a point cloud of type `sensors_msgs.PointCloud2`. I can subscribe to it and read it using `sensors_msgs.point_cloud2.read_points` function but then I get and object of type "generator". How do I access the coordinates of the points in this object?  I want to write a service that checks the maximum allowed height in some specific target areas (the point cloud represents the ceiling). I am using python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240491/point_cloud2.read_points-and-then?/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

read_points gives you a generator (keyword 'yield'). So you can just iterate over it to find your obstacles and not crash your shiny robot

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2

def callback_pointcloud(data):
    assert isinstance(data, PointCloud2)
    gen = point_cloud2.read_points(data)
    print type(gen)
    for p in gen:
      print p  # type depends on your data type, first three entries are probably x,y,z
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/91847/avhi/) on 2021-12-19**:
What would be the other 3 entries ? are they RGB color values ?

**Comment by [bwhal](https://answers.ros.org/users/149128/bwhal/) on 2023-05-15**:
When I use this code, it gives me an assertion error: cloud is not a sensor_msgs.msg.PointCloud2. What would be causing this and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking into the source code I found out that this read_points is a generator function that yields the next value of a cloud each time it is called. It works also as an iterator and calling it in a loop will deliver all pointcloud points:

```
cloud_points = []
for p in point_cloud2.read_points(pc2, field_names = ("x", "y", "z"), skip_nans=True):
    cloud_points.append(p)
```

Here pc2 is my pointcloud of type `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`

and cloud_points will then be a list of 3D points forming the cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ozgurovic](https://answers.ros.org/users/15191/ozgurovic/) on 2017-11-14**:
This would be too slow. Try this instead:

```
cloud_points = list(point_cloud2.read_points(cloud, skip_nans=True, field_names = ("x", "y", "z")))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of ROS2 humble there is also `read_points_numpy` (see [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/60df44894caafa67767da4c71d91f8c5eb7abf38/sensor_msgs_py/sensor_msgs_py/point_cloud2.py#L134)) which would give you directly a 2D NumPy array. For example:

```
cloud = point_cloud2.read_points_numpy(
    msg, field_names=['x', 'y', 'z', "intensity"], skip_nans=True)
```

Note that there also exists a `read_points_list` (see [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/60df44894caafa67767da4c71d91f8c5eb7abf38/sensor_msgs_py/sensor_msgs_py/point_cloud2.py#L165)) at least for galactic, foxy, and humble which would have simplified the code of the other answers.

---

Originally posted by [Lbern](https://answers.ros.org/users/117571/lbern/) with karma: 11 on 2022-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1